# Enabling log cleaner on live kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 10 node kafka cluster with log.cleaner.enable as false. But Now i want to enable it. Since it is not a dynamic property, I guess this change would require broker restart on all the hosts. Can it be done in rolling fashion i.e. restart brokers with log.cleaner.enable= true one by one? Where I am confused is that at some point of time, some partitions of topic would be log compacted but some of them would not be. Will it cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rolling restart is necessary yes.

It would only cause a problem for temporary cleaned topics for consumers that would be reading from leader partitions where the cleaner gets ran. In that case, they would reset to their `auto.offset.reset` positions.

Comment: I did not get what sort of problems part. Can you please elaborate or share some references

Comment: The cleaner is actively removing data. Say there's 10 messages in a topic and the cleaner could remove even offsets less than 8.. A consumer then is polling that data, and as soon as it tries to read a missing offset (say 4), it'll raise a warning and either stop/fail, skip to the smallest available offset (8), or skip to the very end (10), depending on the `auto.offset.reset` (default is latest). Consumers only read from one broker for each partition (the leader); as you're doing a rolling restart, the partition leaders are changing and some might be cleaned while others aren't

Comment: understood, fair callout, thanks for this. I was planning to do this only for __offset topic, so I should be safe, as only the last committed message matters.

Comment: There is not a way to selectively enable the log cleaner on certain topics. The offsets topic is controlled by `offsets.retention.minutes` broker setting, and should always have `cleanup.policy=compact`

Comment: There is not a way to selectively enable the log cleaner on certain topics >> yes, but cleanup.policy for offset topic can be set to [delete, compact] after enabling log cleaner.